# Can't access packages of activated python environment

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04

My code doesn't run without the `#!/usr/bin/python` shebang, it throws error

`import: command not found`.

But I want to run it for other `conda` environment. When I run the code doesn't matter which `conda` env I activate it still fetches the system python's old packages e.g. `opencv 2.4.8` whereas I want to use `4.0.0`

I understand it probably because of that shebang, but is there any way to use other python envs as a default interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

> import: command not found.

Without a shebang Unix recognizes the scripts as a shell script and executes it with `/bin/sh` and of course the shell doesn't know how to interpret a Python script. So either you need a shebang or always execute the script as

```
python script
```

As for the shebang — there is truck to run the script with any python interpreter available in `$PATH` — make the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

[`/usr/bin/env`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/env.html) runs the command searching it in `$PATH`.